# Как добавить JScrollPane к JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

Есть 20 кнопок на панели. Как добавить к этой панели ползунок что бы я мог выбрать кнопку?

**UPD**: добавлен код из комментария

```
for (int c = 0; c < 20; c++) { 
    listButtons.add(new JButton(Integer.toString(c)));
    listButtons.get(c).setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    panels[0].add(listButtons.get(c)); 
} 
panels[0].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red‌​)); 
scroller = new JScrollPane(panels[0]); 
scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERT‌​ICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAY‌​S); 
scroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HO‌​RIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_N‌​EVER); 
add(BorderLayout.EAST , scroller);
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример из [Java JPanel inside JScrollPane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393480/java-jpanel-inside-jscrollpane):

```
public class Scroller extends JFrame {

    public Scroller() throws HeadlessException {
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));

        final JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(panel);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Scroller().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (int c = 0; c < 20; c++) {
            listButtons.add(new JButton(Integer.toString(c)));
            listButtons.get(c).setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
            panels[0].add(listButtons.get(c));
        }
        panels[0].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        scroller = new JScrollPane(panels[0]);
        scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        add(BorderLayout.EAST , scroller);`

Comment: Ползунок добавился, но он не работает

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос, в комментах это плохо читаемо.